# HTTP status was '403 Forbidden' when trying to download spatial polygon dataframe

Tags: r, maps, r-raster

I have a dataset with three variables including latitude, longitude and a continuous variable (*Heart_Disease_Ratio (HDR)*). Every row of this dataset is related to a province in Iran. I want to create the country map of Iran in **R** and to color its provinces according to *HDR* variable. But it returns a status 403 Error when I want to download the spatialpolygondataframe of the world using *getData()* function:

```
library(raster)
library(rworldmap)  ## 1 Get map of provinces (level 1 admin regions)

iranLevel1<- raster::getData("GADM", country = "Iran", level = 1)

 trying URL 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_IRN_2_sp.rds'
 Error in utils::download.file(url = aurl, destfile = fn, method =
 "auto",  :    
cannot open URL 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_IRN_2_sp.rds' 
In addition: Warning message: 
In utils::download.file(url = aurl, destfile = fn, method = "auto",  :   
cannot open URL 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_IRN_2_sp.rds':
     HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

Same thing happens when I try to run the url in the browser.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me to do this in **R** !

**UPDATE**
My problem  is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue comes from the server `https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu` and not raster itself. Hopefully it can be resolved soon

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this replies to the quesiton?

Comment: Thanks @Wanabee,  Is there another way (e.g. another function or package) to visualize a spatial continuous variable on a country map?

Comment: @rudolf_franek wanted to reply as a comment but couldnt because `You must have 50 reputation to comment`

Comment: @Await it seems like raster's server is back up and running on my end